# Why does clearing Derived Data clear up various errors in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Often times, people have various issues or build errors in xcode, and are told to clear Derived Data to fix their particular issue. What is it about Derived Data, that deleting it clears up various issues? What is all contained within Derived Data?

Comment: A lot of build information is stored there, sometimes that information conflicts with the changes you've made and Xcode doesn't update it, so cleaning it up makes sure Xcode is building your code from a completely clean state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode caches a lot of data in that folder, including assets for your app, (images, audio), compiled code/libraries etc.

Xcode does this to speed up the build/run/debug cycle, allowing you to make small changes and rebuilt/test in seconds verses minutes if it had to rebuild every single thing every single time.

But, in some cases, a change you make, won't be detected by Xcode, and thus won't be incorporated into your next build/run. This is when you run into weird issues, some are obvious such as a changed image not be incorporated and you'll see the old image in your build. If the missed change is logic in your code that's not being incorporated, that problem won't be as obvious and can show up as incorrect results or even a crash.

Clearing your Derived Data folder (ideally with Xcode closed), forces a full build next time, at the expense of the extra time required. Of course, that extra time spent compiling is nothing compared to the time trying to debug and find a problem that may not actually exist.

Comment: BTW, I'm the developer of an app called Watchdog for Xcode: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12&uo=4&at=11lMGu&pt=17255&ct=SO that manages the Derived Data folder for you. It will automatically clear it for you at specific times, making your life much easier.